# TypeScript declarations for environment variables not being recognized

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, environment-variables

I am trying to connect to MongoDB when starting my node.js server. My server is in `src/server.ts`, `connectDB()` is in `src/config/db.ts` and my `.env`, and `environment.d.ts` are in the root directory. However, when trying to connect to the DB it still says my `MONGO_URI`, declared in `.env`, is of type `string | undefined`.

`environment.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface ProcessEnv {
    PORT?: string;
    NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production';
    MONGO_URI: string;
  }
}
```

`src/server`:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import connectDB from './config/db';

dotenv.config({ path: '../.env' });
connectDB();
const app = express();

.....
```

`src/config/db.ts`:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    });

    console.log(`MongoDB connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`ERROR: ${error.message}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

export default connectDB;
```

Full error code:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/config/db.ts:5:41 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(uri: string, callback: (err: CallbackError) => void): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(uri: string, options?: ConnectOptions | undefined): Promise<typeof import("mongoose")>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

5     const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
```

I tried declaring the `dotenv.config()` within `db.ts` and removing the path option when declaring it in `server.ts`. Hovering over the environment variable in VSCode shows `(property) NodeJS.ProcessEnv.MONGO_URI: string`. So I really thought this was setup right but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error may be due to your tsconfig.json file rules. Most probably due to `"strictNullChecks": true` you may have put this rule to **true**.
There are two simple solutions:

1. put this rule to **false** like this `"strictNullChecks": false`.
2. Or add `!` immediately after `process.env.MONGO_URI` like this: `process.env.MONGO_URI!`. The symbol `!` insures your typescript transpiler the value will not be **undefined**.

Comment: This does get around the error, but now it still says the parameter I am passing is `undefined` so  I don't know why none of my `.env` variables are none existent even though I have declared them. Edit: moved my server up to the root and changed the path, works now. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 7):

Try to add it inside `global.d.ts` file like this

```js
declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface ProcessEnv {
             PORT?: string;
             NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production';
             MONGO_URI: string;
        }
    }
}

export {};
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me using nextjs

Comment: The `export {};` is what I was missing.